# reading character from keyboard in a while loop

Tags: python, loops, input, keyboard, python-3.x

The following block of code:

```
ans = 'x'
while ans not in ['Y','y','N','n']:
    ans = input("Do Something? [y|n]:")
    print(ans in ['Y','y','N','n'])
```

produces the following output:

```
Do Something? [y|n]:Y
False
Do Something? [y|n]:y
False
Do Something? [y|n]:N
False
Do Something? [y|n]:n
False
Do Something? [y|n]:asdf
False
Do Something? [y|n]:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./NumberPatterns.py", line 27, in <module>
    ans = input("Do Something? [y|n]:")
KeyboardInterrupt
```

I want to read the user's input repeatedly, until it is 'Y','y','N','n'.
But the loop never stops. There must be something that i am missing.
Please help me.

EDIT:
This is the same result of the same code, when run in Interactive Mode:
Version is 3.2.0 on a Windows 7 machine.

```
C:\Users\jwalker>python
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Feb 20 2011, 21:30:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> ans = 'x'
>>> while ans not in ['Y','y','N','n']:
...     ans = input("Do Something? :")
...     print(ans in ['Y','y','N','n'])
...     print(ans, type(ans), len(ans), ord(ans[0]), repr(ans))
...     print('Y', type('Y'), len('Y'), ord('Y'), repr('Y'))
...
Do Something? :asdf
False
 <class 'str'> 5 97 'asdf\r'
Y <class 'str'> 1 89 'Y'
Do Something? :Y
False
 <class 'str'> 2 89 'Y\r'
Y <class 'str'> 1 89 'Y'
Do Something? :n
False
 <class 'str'> 2 110 'n\r'
Y <class 'str'> 1 89 'Y'
Do Something? :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
>>>
>>> ^Z
```

Comment: That's odd.  If I change `input` to `raw_input` to port it to Python 2.6, it works fine for me.  The only guess I have is that `input` is giving a different type.  What prints if you put this in your loop: `print(type(ans), type('Y'))`?

Comment: I agree, but I am wondering what the type could be. Can't think of anything.

Comment: Could you please print the content of `ans`?

Comment: i thought python3 is not stripping `\n` , but the doc says it is stripped...

Comment: very weird, if I use your code on my python3 version, it works like a charm ... you don't type 'Y ' when asking something ?

Comment: -1 due to lack of followup by kafedakias.

Comment: could you `print ans`, `print type(ans)`,  `print len(ans)` etc?  i dont think anybody has clue yet.  Inside you loop, right after you got input from user.

Comment: I executed the same code in Interactive mode with the same results. And i also included info such as `print(ans)` , `print(type(ans))`.

Comment: @kafedakias: Could you provide `print(repr(ans))`?

Comment: Hi Sebastian, i updated the block of my loop to include more information.

Comment: I noticed that a CR escape character is included in the variable `ans`, adding 1 to the length. And also `print(ans,` does not print the content of the variable. But if i use `print(ans)`, it does. About the `ord` and the `repr` i dont even know what they are for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your Python to a more recent version.

You have run afoul of a bug that was introduced in 3.2.0 and almost immediately fixed.  From the bug report:

> In Python 3.2, the builtin function `input()` returns a string with a
>   trailing '\r' on windows:
>
> ```
> C:\Python32>python
> Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Feb 20 2011, 21:29:02) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
> Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
> >>> print(repr(input()))
> test
> 'test\r'
> >>>
> ```

Time line:

- 2011-02-20  [3.2.0 released](http://www.python.org/getit/releases/3.2/)
- 2011-02-21  [issue reported](http://bugs.python.org/issue11272)
- 2011-02-23  [issue fixed](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/aba16a5683d3/)

Comment: I added the execution in interactive mode. version is 3.2 on Windows 7.

Comment: Hmm. I used 3.2 with windows 7 as well.

Comment: `platform.python_version()` shows '3.2.0' could this be a bug in my version?

Comment: Doubtful.  Add this to your loop and let's see what it says:  `print(ans, type(ans), len(ans), ord(ans[0]), repr(ans)),`
`print('Y', type('Y'), len('Y'), ord('Y'), repr('Y'))`

Answer (score 1):

That code works perfectly well in Python 3.2:

```
>>> ans = 'x'
>>> while ans not in ['Y','y','N','n']:
...    ans = input("Do Something? [y|n]:")
...    print(ans in ['Y','y','N','n'])
Do Something? [y|n]:y
True
>>>
```

This makes me suspect that your question is a hint more complicated than your basic example. Where are you running the code? Is it in a function which is inside of a loop?

Comment: The code is not inside a function or any other form of container.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT This answer is for Python-2, so this is not answering to a question tagged with Python-3.x. Please do not consider it.

---

According to [Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#input), you should use `raw_input()`:

> Consider using the raw_input() function for general input from users.

That's because `input()` is not what you expect:

> input([prompt])
>
> ```
> Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
> ```

This is not really what you need here, as highlighted by your comment.

Comment: the tag for the Q says python-3.x so this guy may by using that.  it seems correct for me.

Comment: The question is tagged python-3.x so `raw_input` is not available.

Comment: mmh, good point. I edit my answer to mark it as irrelevant, as Py3k document says that it should.

Comment: -1.  He's using Python 3 as evinced by the python-3.x tag and the print *function*.  Also, if you run it unmodified on python-2.x it won't work like he shows, but give a `NameError` after the first input.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: I know why I was not aware of Python version: `print()` is working in Python 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

try trimming the text with strip():

```
ans = 'x'
while ans.strip() not in ['Y','y','N','n']:
    ans = raw_input("Do Something? [y|n]:")
    print(ans.strip() in ['Y','y','N','n'])
```